# Best way to process only new commits in an update hook

Tags: git, githooks

I am writing a server side update hook, and want to process only the commits of a push that were not in the repository before the push, i.e. the commits that are being introduced by the push. At first I was going to do `git rev-list <oldrefvalue>..<newrefvalue>`, but that can include existing commits if one of the new commits is a merge of an existing branch. I've come up with a couple ways of doing it, none of which thrill me:

1. For each commit in `git rev-list <oldrefvalue>..<newrefvalue>`, do `git rev-list --all | grep <commit>` to see if it is an existing commit (obviously I would cache the results of `git rev-list --all`).
2. Do `git for-each-ref --format="^%(objectname)" refs/heads | xargs git rev-list <newrefvalue>` to get all commits reachable by the pushed ref but not reachable through any of the existing branches

Are either of these approaches preferable to the other, or is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you really want to use the `update` hook, something like

```
git rev-list <newrefvalue> --not --branches --tags
```

should do what you need. It will skip all commits which already exist in any branch or tag. But it will run several times if several branches are pushed with same new commits. You could avoid it with using `pre-receive` hook instead, which handles all ref updates at once, and getting the whole list of new commits as:

```
git rev-list <newrefvalue1> <newrefvalue2> .. <newrefvalueN> --not --branches --tags
```

In short test it looks like it outputs each commit only once.

Note that it works only for hooks which run *before* the ref updates, which are `udpate` and `pre-receive`. It does not work for `post-update` for example.